# smallIcon do local notification não aparece IONIC

Tags: ionic, local-notification

Preciso alterar o smallIcon do meu local notification, porém já defini o local no meu resources mas mesmo assim não aparece.

Tentei algo como:

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({
              id: i+1,
              text: 'Produto: ' + res.data.notificar.perguntas[i].produto.substring(0,20) + '...',
              title: 'Nova pergunta, conta: ' + res.data.notificar.perguntas[i].conta,
              icon: 'https://image.ibb.co/gnUHn9/Iconnotificacao.png',
              smallIcon: 'res://iconnotificacao',
              priority: 2,
```

Meu icone de notificação está localizado em:

PastaDoProjeto/resources/iconnotificacao.png

Informações do ionic/cordova:

Ionic:

```
 ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 13 other plugins)
```

Answer (score 0):

O smallicon do LocalNotification tem que possuir a extersão correta do arquivo (.jpg, ou .png, etc).

Teste assim:

```
smallIcon: 'res://iconnotificacao.png'
```

Substitua pela extensão do seu arquivo.